# Rd files with different encoding

Tags: r, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, devtools

How do I specify encoding for rd file correctly? I'm trying to add the following help file documenting dummy function to my package:

```
\name{dummy}
\encoding{ISO-8859-2}
\alias{dummy}
\title{Příšerně žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.}
\usage{
  dummy(x)
}
\arguments{
  \item{x}{Příšerně žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské
  ódy.Příšerně žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.}
}
\description{
  Příšerně žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.Příšerně
  žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.
}
\examples{
dummy(x="Příšerně žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.Příšerně žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.")
}
```

However, when I try to install my package (using `install` from `devtools`) I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In fetch(key) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
2: In strsplit(msg, "\n") : input string 1 is invalid in this locale
```

When I try `help(dummy)` I get:

```
Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database '�' is corrupt
```

Any advice?

Comment: Probably clean your environment, with `rm(ls=list())` and `source()` and try again?!?

Comment: Take a look here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file You should be able to specify encoding in your DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: You'll need to restart R between invocations of `install`.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this encoding might not be well handled by R. 
If I copy paste your function in a fake package, remove the mention to your encoding in the Rd file and save it with encoding UTF-8 and add

```
    Encoding: UTF-8
```

To the DESCRIPTION file it works fine (under linux, with UTF-8 local).